# What is the proper way to call paintComponent?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, paintcomponent

I'm new to Java GUI and I'm trying to get this program to display a square when a button is clicked. Nothing happens because repaint() does not work on paintComponent(Graphics g).  I have searched and some said to use an Event dispatch thread but I am still very confused

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Ham extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    JPanel p1;
    JButton b1;
    public Ham(){
        setSize(600, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        p1 = new JPanel();
        b1 = new JButton("Check");
        b1.addActionListener(this);
        p1.add(b1);
        add(p1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
        if(e.getSource() == b1){
            repaint();
        }
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(100,100,50,50);        
    }
}
```

Comment: I regret taking the time to answer this question. I just noticed that you have asked 10 questions on the forum and not once have to taken the time to accept an answer to your question. I guess you don't appreciate the help we give you.

Comment: sorry I **just** found out you can do that

Comment: do appreciate the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JFrame does not have a paintComponent() method.

Custom painting is done by overriding the `paintComponent()` method of a `JPanel` (or JComponent). You should also override the `getPreferredSize()` method of the panel to return a reasonable value. Then you add the panel to the frame.

You can then invoke `repaint()` on the panel and the paintComponent() method will be invoked.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and examples.